# Python AWS Lambda deploy - Zappa unable to update lambda configuration

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

I am facing an issue in pipeline deployment with Zappa - unable to update lambda configuration. It shows below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 3415, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 588, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 644, in dispatch_command
    self.vargs["docker_image_uri"],
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 1174, in update
    wait=False,
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 1408, in update_lambda_configuration
    if lambda_aws_config["PackageType"] != "Image":
KeyError: 'PackageType'
```

It was working previously file but now when I run the pipeline its starts failing. I have not done any changes to requirements.txt it is the same as the previous successful pass.

The version of Python is 3.7 and
AWS is running in `us-east-1` region.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Zappa 0.54.1 fixes this issue as a wait function has been included to collect the correct key params from AWS.

Comment: It didn't solve it for me. Anyone else experiencing the same issue?